# position_stack and inversion of percentage labels in a stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with the position_stack function in a stacked barplot.
As you can see from the image below in some cases I have an inversion on the percentage value labels.

[image]

Here are my data:

```
id  val          time   var     label
1   19.00499584   EX    diet1   19.00
2   -24.35452794  EX    diet1   -24.35
3   -18.58325667  EX    diet1   -18.58
4   -15.50364964  EX    diet1   -15.50
5   27.60230706   EX    diet1   27.60
6   1.150442478   EX    diet1   1.15
7   -5.930055753  EX    diet1   -5.93
1   -1.403798514  EX+D  diet1   -1.40
2   12.21098266   EX+D  diet1   12.21
3   36.79131484   EX+D  diet1   36.79
4   10.17820425   EX+D  diet1   10.18
5   -10.62221361  EX+D  diet1   -10.62
6   8.333333333   EX+D  diet1   8.33
7   1.658653846   EX+D  diet1   1.66
1   4.391357808   EX    diet2   4.39
2   12.01472557   EX    diet2   12.01
3   -2.628676471  EX    diet2   -2.63
4   8.408871745   EX    diet2   8.41
5   9.160170092   EX    diet2   9.16
6   7.447067413   EX    diet2   7.45
7   1.706231454   EX    diet2   1.71
1   5.962616822   EX+D  diet2   5.96
2   54.31421446   EX+D  diet2   54.31
3   -21.25925926  EX+D  diet2   -21.26
4   20.72234763   EX+D  diet2   20.72
5   9.864004132   EX+D  diet2   9.86
6   12.9842615    EX+D  diet2   12.98
7   22.89185905   EX+D  diet2   22.89
```

Here is my code:

```
bx <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\...f1.csv", sep=";")
bx$time<-factor(bx$time, levels=c("EX", "EX+D"))
bx$id<-factor(bx$id)
bx$var<-factor(bx$var, levels=c("diet1", "diet2"))


vv<-ggplot(bx, aes(id, val)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = time)) + geom_hline(yintercept=0)+ facet_grid(var~.)+ coord_flip()+geom_text(aes(label = label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size = 4, color="black")

vv+ scale_fill_grey(start=0.8, end=0.5)+labs(x="Obs", y="Percentage difference", fill="Time") + theme_bw() + theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),  
     strip.text.x = element_text(size=12, angle=45), 
     strip.background = element_rect(fill="white"))
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to have absolute values (i.e., no negative signs in front of numbers) as labels? Then `abs(x)` would be your function of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be defining `aes` in 3 places: in your initial `ggplot()` in `geom_bar()` and in `geom_text()`.

Instead, do one `aes` definition in `ggplot()` i.e. and let `geom_bar` and `geom_text` inherit the `aes` you define in  `ggplot()`.

For example, where you have:

```
vv<-ggplot(bx, aes(id, val)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = time)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+ facet_grid(var~.)+
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            size = 4, color="black")
```

Instead, change that to:

```
vv<-ggplot(bx, aes(id, val, fill=time, label =label)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+ facet_grid(var~.)+ 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            size = 4, color="black")
```

That results in the positioning you wanted for the labels:
[image]

I'll leave it to you to tweak the size of the label text to suit your output format/use.

Comment: So smart!!!! Thank you! This's great! Can I ask you why I'm not able to change the angle of "diet1" and "diet2" label text? I've tried with `strip.text.x = element_text(size=12, angle=45)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I fixed it! I have to use `strip.text.y`